# Phone number regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to check regular expression and if it doesn't match alerts 'invalid' but my problem is regular expression doesn't work

```
$("#SendPhone").click(function() {
  var phonePattern = /(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}/;
  if ($("#PhoneField").val() == '' || !$("#PhoneField").match(phonePattern) == false) {
    alert("it is invalid")
  }
}
```

i worked with this code in javascript pure it worked but in jquery doesnt work

this is whole jquery code snippet:

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#SendPhone").click(function() {
          var phonePattern = /(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}/;
          if ($("#PhoneField").val() == '') {
              alert("it is invalid")
          }


          var phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val();
          $.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'insert.php',
              data:{'phoneField':phoneField},
              success:(function (response) {
              })
          })
          $.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'show.php',
              data:{},
              success:(function (response) {
                  $("#CodeField").val(response);
              })
          })
      });
  });
```

Comment: Can you post the full jquery snippet ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay other parts are OK

Comment: To fix this we need to know what you expect should/should not be matched. Also note that `match()` returns an array or `null`

Comment: `$("#PhoneField").match`  did you mean `$("#PhoneField").val().match` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your regular expression is the right one, then you need to change your code as follows (the `match` string method does not return a boolean, it's either an array with the matches or `null`) :

```
$("#SendPhone").click(function() {
    var phonePattern = /(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}/;
    if ($("#PhoneField").val() == '' || !$("#PhoneField").match(phonePattern)) {
        alert("it is invalid");
    }
});
```

Comment: No it's not, I removed the `== false` to not restrict the equality so now when the `match` function returns `null`, the evaluation in the `if` is `!null` which is equal to `true`. This way your alert will be executed.